# Move features to different geographic area

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis

I want to move a dataset of a few thousand vectors to a different geographic area. However I can't seem to find any tools to do this, or I'm not sure on the terminology for what to look up.

I suppose a common example of what I would like are maps that show the true size of Antarctica when overlaying other continents. However, size comparison isn't my actual goal if it makes a difference; any size, direction, or shape distortion isn't a concern. My intent is to obfuscate the real location while still being able to show geographic features.

My preferred tool is QGIS but I can use ArcMap or PostGIS.

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you are trying to do. Have you tried playing around with the layer symbology to get what you want (hide or show feature names, certain classes, etc.)? A screenshot would help.

Comment: There are a couple of simple options. The answer suggested is just to select everything and move it. Another option would be to simply Define the data as a different projection - not reproject it, but define it as the wrong CRS. In both cases though it could be potentially easy to 'un-obfuscate' the data if there's enough there to determine what/where it should really be. Having some idea of the data you're working with and why you want to obfuscate it might be helpful. For instance with point data one option is to randomize the locations.

Comment: https://youtu.be/JpVavGmHmDI here you can get complete details abdout move feature.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164987)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If all the features are in the same geodatabase & dataset, or even better in the same feature class, I am sure that In ArcMap you could begin editing the layers with the Editor toolbar, right click on the feature name in the ToC, under 'Selection' 'Select All', & use the Editor Tool [image: Edit Tool in Editor Toolbar] to move the features wherever you would like. In QGIS, you could import the dataset, toggle editing, choose the 'Select Features' tool [image: Select Features tool in QGIS], & then click the 'Move Feature(s)' button, & then drag the features wherever you would like. [image: QGIS Edit & Move Feature(s) tools]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

In case you can't find the **Move Feature**-Button, like me, you need to enable the **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar** via right-clicking on the toolbar. Seems like a recent QGIS version set this toolbar to be hidden by default.
It appears to me like this after enabling it:
[image]

Comment: this helped as a user of QGIS Bialowieza LTR.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin in QGIS called "Move Features". It may help.
Download link:https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/moving_feature/