# How to group many points in the same point and colour it by value?

Tags: qgis, point, heat-map

I have coordinates of car incidents and I have to draw a map.

The coordinates are not precise: as you can see in the image below you can see the coordinates of 10 incidents and the crossroards where they happened. The points are very close but not in the same position. I need to group all the points in the same points to *draw a figure coloured by the number of points**

eg:

- 10 points => red
- 5 points => orange
- single point => yellow

I use QGIS 3.10 on Windows.

[image: separated-points]

update: the points are now grouped on the same point using move feature

Comment: a) The image is missing. b) What does "draw a coloured figure" mean?

Comment: Do you wanna group all the points that share the same cell in order to create your heat map ?

Comment: I need to move all the points over a single point

Comment: You have the "move feature" tool that might answer to your question ! (check the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpVavGmHmDI&feature=youtu.beat) at 1:19)

It has been already discussed here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139840/move-features-to-different-geographic-area

Comment: Have you looked at the Snap processing tool?  If you have or create points for each intersection then you can snap your incidents to the points in that layer.

Comment: Another approach could be buffering: create a buffer of let's say 20 meters and dissolve all the buffers, than create the centroid of the resulting polygons

Comment: Still another approach is using clustering layer styling: choose a distance setting long enough that all your points laying close by are represented by just one symbol (so differing from the buffer-approach, in the clustering-approach you don't change any geometry, just the symbolization)